# Sample size confidence limit

Tags: sample-size, sample, statistical-power

I'm reading this text and wanted to know how they calculated the 95% confidence interval when calculating sample size and what it means:

> "The sample size is 150 so that for a response rate of 80% there is 80%
>   power that the confidence limits between 71% and 89%  cover the
>   estimate of the ORR."

How is this calculated and how can I find the confidence interval for different sample sizes, e.g. 50 with response rate of 0.8 and 0.9. What formula is used?

Comment: +1.  It takes some thought to make sense of this convoluted, ambiguous, and technically meaningless statement.  The confidence interval is *guaranteed* to cover the ORR by construction.  The authors' likely intended meaning is conveyed by deleting the words "the estimate of."